# How can I monitor Windows XP internet history over a network? (Im ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: networking, internet, sharing, parental-controls

I believe my daughter is visiting websites that she shouldn't be on. She does that from a desktop with Windows XP. Is there a program that will let me view what websites she visits over a network while I'm on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Any possible answer to this question (including the answers so far) will fundamentally be about Windows XP and the way files are stored in the Windows XP system, or how the Windows XP system can be (perhaps surreptitiously) configured to allow remote access.

Comment: This might not need to involve anything more than shared network protocols ; a packet sniffer or logging proxy might do the trick. (I've left an answer to this effect.)

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is Firefox 3 (or newer) you could share over network the mozilla folder where the file `places.sqlite` is stored. This file can be analysed by [sqlitebrowser [image: Install sqlitebrowser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlitebrowser) for example.

Comment: It says that I dont have sufficient permissions to view her files even though I shared all folders underneath her C:/ drive.

Comment: I think you have to change file sharing settings in Windows network preferences so that others users are able to view the files

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it somehow, but keep in mind that if your daughter uses private browsing or incognito mode (just press ctrl+shift+P on IE, ot ctrl+shift+n on chrome, no other installations), that method will not work at all and it would be undetectable.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this to some degree by using something like `wireshark`, listening over the network segment (that is, you'll need to be on the same switch, and in the same vlan if that's applicable).   This won't work for encrypted traffic (https, ssh, etc.), but many web sites send data in the clear.  This is more complicated if trying to sniff traffic wirelessly, but there are programs such as aircrack that can get you started. 
Another option is to set up a dedicated proxy (squid, etc.), that acts as an intermediate layer between the target PC and the router.  It has a number of functions, but it can also log traffic sources and destinations (such as web sites). 
You can also use something like OpenDNS, which does some logging, and can filter various categories -- it does this by redirecting DNS lookups to "bad" sites.  It requires that the target PC is pointed to OpenDNS for name resolution, however.